# HTML - calling javascript by clicking on image

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call javascript by clicking on the image but it's not working.
Please refer below for my code.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="images/Image_1.png"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="images/Image_2.png"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="images/Image_3.png"
//-->

  function login(showhide){
    if(showhide == "show"){
        document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="visible";
    }else if(showhide == "hide"){
        document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="hidden"; 
    }
  }
  </script>
```

my code

```
<div id="apDiv21"><img src="images/Login_OnOut.png" width="71" height="44" 
onmouseover="this.src='images/Login_OnRollover.png'" 
  onmouseout="this.src='images/Login_OnOut.png'" onclick="login('show');" />

  <div id="popupbox"> 
<form name="login" action="" method="post" style="background-color:#C7C7C7">
<center>Username:</center>
<center><input name="username" size="14" /></center>
<center>Password:</center>
<center><input name="password" type="password" size="14" /></center>
<center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" /></center>
</form>
<center><a href="login('hide');">close</a></center> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this JSFiddle I made:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5asp/

I changed the link at the bottom to properly hide it.  The problem was that when you used `Login('show')` it was trying to access your form because it was the same name.  You must make sure that your function name and names don't conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the attribute `name="login"` from the `form` tag. It now pollutes the name space so that the JavaScript interpreter takes the name `login` as referring to the form node rather than your function. (Firefox console error message says “login is not a function” for this reason.) – You can alternatively rename the form, but there’s normally no need for a `name` attribute for a form.

P.S. The edit you made to the question was wrong. Correct markup for a text that is to be clickable is `<a onclick="login('hide');">close</a>` (though for useability, it would be better to use a button).